# Joomla 3 params from another template

Tags: php, joomla, parameters, joomla3.0

Is it possible to get the template parameters from one template into another template? And if so how? I am basically trying to reuse some parameters I have in my main template in one that I am doing for IE8 an less users.

Comment: Why would you use a completely different template for users using older browsers? Why not adapt your currently template?

Comment: Its IE 8, I am only wanting to display a message to them, not give them a dumbed down site. Besides if I don't use modern techniques what is the point of having modern techniques!

Comment: In that case have a look at the ie8 upgrade plugins as this might be what you're looking for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a much cleaner means to achieve the same thing.  For the sample code I'm loading Joomla 3.2 included Protostar template's manifest file and retrieving the template color field.

```
jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');
$params = new JRegistry(JFile::read(JPATH_ROOT . '/templates/protostar/templateDetails.xml'));
$color = $params->get('templateColor');
```

Comment: Agreed, this is a much better solution than mine. I didn't know that something like that existed!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes across this in the future here is what I finally figure out how to do. If someone has a better solution, please post.

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$sql = "SELECT params FROM `#__template_styles` WHERE `id` = 9"; //Set equal to template id
$db->setQuery($sql); 
$db->query();
$row = $db->loadRow();
$json = $row[0];

$arrayExtract = json_decode($json, true);
extract($arrayExtract, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "dup");
//Note: this will add an underscore to end of dup
//      in all my searching, I never saw it documented
//      stumbled upon it by accident

//templateDetails.xml -> params 
echo $dup_logoText . "<br>";
echo $dup_Address . "<br>";
```

I could see this being utilized for an intranet type situation, where one wanted to use the params from the main template in the intranet template, not just for the IE 8 workaround as was in my original question.